# Rails console can't connect to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

In last days i update my OS X to Maverics. Today when i try to create new project like this:

```
rails new abc
```

there were many problems but i install xcode and now it's work. Right now i open rails console like this:

```
rails console
```

and then whatever i write i only see:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 4.0.1)
1.9.3p448 :001 > Link
=> Link(no database connection)
```

What is wrong? Mysql is running, database exist. When i do rake db:migrate everything works fine.

Comment: are you sure your `database.yml` is correct for development environment..

Comment: yes im sure otherwise rake db:migrate wont working

Comment: I have the same issue after I upgraded my app to rails 4. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19940307/issue-abouot-populate-in-rails4

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The console probably **does** have a database connection but is reporting that it doesn't.

To see if that's true, make a query in the console.

```
Link.count
```

That fixed the false positive warning for me and a colleague.

Comment: Same here. Definitely a bug

Comment: @JosephJaber's comment makes me think this isn't a bug.

Comment: The message has been changed in Rails 4.1 to be more clear. See @juanitofatas answer below.

Comment: it fixes the false positive but only while the console is still open. once you exit and reenter it happens all over again. see Joseph Jaber's answer to fix

Answer (score 29):

In the past, referencing an ActiveRecord model immediately after loading the console would return its column information. Rails now only returns this information if it has been explicitly coerced to connect to the database by a method like `connection`, `first`, `all`, `count`, etc.

You can restore the previous behavior by adding this to your `config/application.rb`

```
console do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection
end
```

Answer (score 19):

According to [the issues #12804](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12804) on [rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails).

> The message just tells you that AR has not yet connected to the database and therefore does not know the column information. I think it's desired not to connect to the database unless we need to fetch data.

For now you could use `Model.connection` to establish a connection.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is a terrible choice of wording and behaviour though.

Comment: This was the solution that fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

Try using `reload!` on the console and ensure that you have records in the specified model if not create records for the relations etc..

I had the same problem on ubuntu. I used `reload!` in rails console and added records in the database.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having the same issue with Rails 4.0.1. It's occurring on the Linux server I'm deploying to as well as my Mavericks development machine.

The server works, specs work, but the console doesn't have a database connection.

Reverting to Rails 4.0.0 fixes the issue with the console.

I haven't found any other mention of this issue. There's probably an issue with the changes for 4.0.1 and the Postgres adapter, maybe? (Are you using Postgres?)

Comment: no i am using mysql on ubuntu running in vagrant virtual machine.